# Expanding a dataframe with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I would like to expand a dataframe with duplicates of its own elements, but with specific conditions.

Here is my example data:

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x2 <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
y1 <- c(9, 9, 8, 9, 9)
y2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(x1, x2, y1, y2)
df   

  x1 x2 y1 y2
1  1  2  9  0
2  2  2  9  0
3  3  2  8  0
4  4  2  9  1
5  5  2  9  1
```

The condition: only duplicate if y1 = 9 and y2 = 0. Therefore the output should look like this:

```
  x1 x2 y1 y2
1  1  2  9  0
2  2  2  9  0
3  3  2  8  0
4  4  2  9  1
5  5  2  9  1
6  1  2  9  0
7  2  2  9  0
```

Case 1 and 2 were duplicated and accordingly the dataframe was expanded (new rows 6 and 7). Case 3, 4 and 5 were ignored, the condition was not met.

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the row index of the rows which satisfies our condition using `which` and just `rbind` those rows together to the original data frame.

```
inds <- which(df$y1 == 9 & df$y2 == 0)
rbind(df, df[inds,])

#  x1 x2 y1 y2
#1  1  2  9  0
#2  2  2  9  0
#3  3  2  8  0
#4  4  2  9  1
#5  5  2  9  1
#6  1  2  9  0
#7  2  2  9  0
```

---

Or using `dplyr` `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df, 
df %>%
  filter(y1 == 9 & y2 == 0))
```

---

If we want to change the values for the duplicated rows for `y1` to 10, we can do

```
bind_rows(df, 
          df %>%
            filter(y1 == 9 & y2 == 0) %>% 
            mutate(y1 = 10)
          )

#  x1 x2 y1 y2
#1  1  2  9  0
#2  2  2  9  0
#3  3  2  8  0
#4  4  2  9  1
#5  5  2  9  1
#6  1  2 10  0
#7  2  2 10  0
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Is there a way to change values for example for y1 at the same time? For example: case 6 and 7 (the duplicated rows) get a 10 instead of a 9 in y1.